# Regex-replace certains string with a range of numbers following after

Tags: java, regex, string, syntax, integer

Okay. So im dealing with cells where certain values need to be removed. In my comment in the code below there is two String examples. I want to create a String that can replace the string at the end with its 8 numbers too. Keep in mind that Im really looking for an algorithm that takes the 8 numbers right after "cvr" and not the text value at the end of a cell as this string could also be at the start.

//dontReplaceme 12345678  ||   cvr 87654321

```
String replaceCVRs = textValueForCPR.replaceAll("|CVR|Cvr|cvr|"+ (8 numbers after???))
```

Comment: `String replaceCVRs = textValueForCPR.replaceAll("(?i)(cvr)\\d{8}", "$1")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew   Your answer seems to work. However, it only works when there is no space between "cvr" and the 8 numbers. What if theres "" between them? Can I somehow express that in this line of code?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Once again thanks again. It worked! However, I still got another small related question. How do I allow it to delete numbers ranging from having 1 -8. Because there are some cvrs with less than 8 numbers that I also wanna delete.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
String replaceCVRs = textValueForCPR.replaceAll("(?i)(cvr)\\s*\\d{1,8}", "$1")
```

**NOTE**: If you want to fail the match if there are more digits after an 8-digit number add `(?!\d)` lookahead at the end, `"(?i)(cvr)\\s*\\d{1,8}(?!\\d)"`.

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/c3wtL1/2).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode on
- `(cvr)` - Group 1: `cvr`  string
- `\s*`  - 0 or more whitespaces
- `\d{1,8}` - one to eight digits.